# Gson filter fields at runtime based on actual object, not reference

Tags: json, gson

ExcludeStrategy in Gson allows you to filter fields based on reference type. But due to polymorphism, we can have an object that contains much more fields. Which basically means ExcludeStrategy is actually useless in this case. I think this was quite a bad design in Gson.

The issue is that by getting the field, you can find out what class/interface that field was declared in, but can't find out what is the actual instance that is currently processed by Gson. So you can't use ExcludeStrategy other than for pretty basic models, not for hierarchies.

Is there a way to tell Gson what fields to log and which to skip, **without using annotations**, at runtime?

Maybe something like `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` in Jackson framework?

Comment: I'm afraid, Gson does not provide anything like that. You might like to refer https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java -- as you can see, `excluder` only accepts fields, not actual objects. The only thing I can suggest is creating separate DTOs without properties you are not interested in.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't see anything that would do it. DTO solution won't work. I want to dynamically decide what I want to let pass and what not. E.g. I have a config file that I change and in that I specify what fields should be converted.

Comment: What gson would need is to include the class of the processed object in the FieldAttributes. It wouldn't break the contract I think and would allow for such filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything for this. I've opened an issue with a suggestion of how to get this outcome, but so far no updates:

https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1272

Follow that issue for an update. I'll also update this answer whenever there's any progress.